# What is the recommendation for location of log files for Android App?

Tags: android, logging

Can someone please help me on what is best way to create log file with all the restrictions by android like
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

Basically i am interested in recommendation of location of the log file were it should be placed

I was using  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() till now which is deprecated.

Comment: You should probably describe how the log files will be used/accessed. Would those file/files be accessed by a third-party app or via end user instructions or what?

Comment: it will be used by end user.. Basically its for debugging purpose. For example: if the app crashes... Or notification fails to reach the device due to our business logic.. Or a feature is not working in particulate device we ask users to share the logs

Answer (score 1):

Android 11 is indeed very restricted. Why aren't you using the default android.util.Log for this? If there is a good reason and you do not need to expose it to the user itself other than via the application, just put it in the application folder (context.filesDir, see https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#internal). If you want to have it externally available, you need to request permissions, start an intent for folder selection and store the permission for later use. I advice against this, unless you truly need it.

Short (incomplete) example of how to go with writing a log to file.

```
object Out {
    private var dLogFile: File = null

    fun init(ctx: Context) {
        dLogFile = File(ctx.filesDir, "status.log")
        if (dLogFile.length() > 512 * 1024) FileUtil.moveFile(dLogFile)
        FileUtil.writeLines(dLogFile, "== Status log @ ${DateUtil.getPrintDate(DateTime.now())} ==")
    }
    
    fun i(tag: String, line: String) {
        Log.i(tag, line)
        FileUtil.writeLines(dLogFile, getTag('I', tag) + line)
    }
}

object FileUtil {
    fun writeLines(logFile: File?, vararg lines: String?) {
        FileWriter(logFile, true).use {
            for (line in lines) {
                it.write(line)
                it.write(NEWLINE)
            }
            it.flush()
        }
    }
}
```

Regards, Mike

Comment: with android.util.Log will be able to write to a file? so that user can send it if ther is any breakage?

Comment: In such a case you need to write it to file. Make sure you rotate it. I'll update the answer for an example.